# installing jdk1.6 and netbeans on opensolaris2008.11

Tags: netbeans6.5, java-6

i installed jdk 1.6 using both the .sh( jdk-6u12-solaris-x64.sh ) and the .tar.Z(jdk-6u12-solaris-x64.tar.Z) files but neither the command prompt nor the netbeans installer is detecting the installation. wat is the correct way to install the jdk on opensolaris?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and set JAVA_HOME?

export JAVA_HOME = /path/to/java

Then try java -version at a command prompt and see what you get.